# linux - how to change directory and run a command on startup using rc.local

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am running ubunto on a box in ec2. I would like to execute the following command in a specific directory each time the machine starts up:

```
celery -A someapp.tasks --concurrency=1 --loglevel=info worker > output.log 2> errors.log
```

I've run

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

and edited the file to read

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
(
    cd /home/ubuntu/somefolder/
    sh -e -c 'celery -A someapp.tasks worker -Ofair --loglevel=info > output.log > errors.log'
)
exit 0
```

But when the server starts up the command doesnt run. If I cd directly into /home/ubunto/somefolder and run the celery command the operation starts as expected. How can I run this command each time the machine starts up?

Comment: have you tried "cd directly into /home/ubunto/somefolder and run the celery command" as root user?

Comment: i.e. $ sudo celery ... ? I haven't tried that, but understand that the permission implications of this.

Comment: or even `sudo su -` and then cd ... and celery ..., in case the permission problem already affects the directory

Comment: Where is `celery`? It may not be in the default `$PATH`.

Comment: @StefanHegny when I run `sudo su -` I cannot change the pwd with `cd /home/ubuntu/somefolder/`. if I execute `ls` it returns nothing. `pwd` just gives `\root` .

Comment: I hope you understood, `sudo su -` give you a new (root) prompt at which then you do the cd ... etc. I can hardly imagine that cd will not work and neither show any error message like 'permission denied', 'directory does not exist' or alike?

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this, using a subshell, so you don't change `rc.local`'s working dir:

```
(
  cd /home/ubuntu/somefolder 
  celery -A someapp.tasks --concurrency=1 --loglevel=info worker >output.log 2> errors.log
)
exit 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I've tried the enclosing brackets but no dice. I'll update my question to reflect the new state of rc.local

Comment: Ah I see. Can you try this for me? `cd /home/ubuntu/somefolder` then `sh -e -c 'celery -A someapp.tasks --concurrency=1 --loglevel=info worker > output.log 2> errors.log'`

Comment: I've edited the file as suggested (updated code in question too) but still no dice. To test I added the edits. Stopped the machine. Then started it up again. Upon checking, the celery command hadn't been run :/

Comment: Sorry I meant just run this manually on the command line and see if it works.

Comment: not working for me as well but tried a different command. Might be with how the etc folder is located?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the following:

```
sudo vi /etc/crontab
```

Add this at the end:

```
@reboot  cd /home/ubuntu/somefolder/ && sh -e -c 'celery -A someapp.tasks worker -Ofair --loglevel=info > output.log > errors.log'
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this one:

```
cd /home/ubuntu/somefolder && celery -A someapp.tasks --concurrency=1 --loglevel=info worker >output.log 2> errors.log
```